# Unexpected Errors on publishing figure to html by MATLAB in Linux

Tags: html, matlab, publish, figure

I am using MATLAB to publish HTML report. In the .m script, I have some plot functions to produce graphs. While I was running the script in the MATLAB GUI, it works perfectly fine as I expected.

However, the problems came, I need to run the script from the command line such that to save time, when I ran the script from command line, the HTML file was still produced but all the figures became distorted. All of them went to resolution of 520 x 460, I didn't really know why this happen.

To solve the problem, I tried to change the publish option specified in this page: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/specifying-output-preferences-for-publishing.html
But they don't seems to help.

Do anyone of you have any ideas? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you start matlab via command line, is java available? http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/usejava.html Afaik plotting has very limited capabilities when java is not available.

Comment: I use matlab's publish from within shell scripts with a command like `matlab -r "publish demo_myfunction; exit"` .  This launches the Matlab GUI, runs the script, generates the HTML and images, then exits Matlab.  It works fine, and allows you to automate publishing without having to resort to the `matlab -nojvm` command prompt.